# Detect barcode scanner with PointOfService on Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner

I would like to use a barcode scanner with Windows 10 (Build 15063) via the Windows.Devices.PointOfService namespace. The scanner is a Datalogic Quickscan QD2430 and I tried with all RS-232 and Keyboard mode.

I used the official sample application https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner with no luck. It can detect a device but it's definitely the in-built webcam (HP laptop).

I tried to modify the source, the DeviceHelpers's GetFirstDeviceAsync function https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/SharedContent/cs/DeviceHelpers.cs.

The DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync also returns only the camera's info as result.

```
string selector = BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector(PosConnectionTypes.All);
DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

It returns nothing.

```
DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.ImageScanner);
```

It returns every connected and I think the previously connected but currently offline devices too. I tried to filter the scanner by name. There was a lot filterd result too, but the convertAsync function returned null for all excepts one, it thrown an Exception "A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)".

```
DeviceInformationCollection infos = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.All);
foreach(DeviceInformation info in infos)
{
    if (info.Name.ToUpper().Contains("BARCODE"))
    {
        T scanner = await convertAsync(info.Id);
        if (scanner != null)
        {
            return scanner;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only a guess, you probably need to install the driver for the scanner if you want to use anything more the keyboard wedge mode

Comment: I installed the driver for the "USB Com to simulate RS-232 standard interface" mode and I am able to capture data via the SerialPort class, but sometimes it throws Access Denied on COMx port exception when I want to use it, and the only solution is a device re-connection, that's why I want to accomplish the read with the PointOfService.

Answer (score 0):

Datalogic Quickscan QD2430 is not in the [list of devices supported by Windows.Devices.PointOfService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support).

Ask Datalogic to provide a device driver that supports Windows.Devices.PointOfService, or change the scanner to the one described in the supported list.

Alternatively, create your own device driver according to the [Point of Service (POS) of Windows Driver Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/_pos/).